# Reflect camera in translated plane

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I have the plane `z = 0` and want to reflect my camera in this plane. My code works well, as long as I don't translate the plane along the z-Axis.
My current attempt looks like this:

```
//transform the plane in world coordinates
vec4 waterPlane = modelMatrix.inverse().transpose() * vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
//calculate reflection matrix
mat4 mReflection = mat4
(
  1.0 - 2.0 * waterPlane.getX() * waterPlane.getX(), -2.0 * waterPlane.getX() * waterPlane.getY(), -2.0 * waterPlane.getX() * waterPlane.getZ(), -2.0 * waterPlane.getX() * waterPlane.getL(),
  -2.0 * waterPlane.getX() * waterPlane.getY(), 1.0 - 2.0 * waterPlane.getY() * waterPlane.getY(), -2.0 * waterPlane.getY() * waterPlane.getZ(), -2.0 * waterPlane.getY() * waterPlane.getL(),
  -2.0 * waterPlane.getX() * waterPlane.getZ(), -2.0 * waterPlane.getY() * waterPlane.getZ(), 1.0 - 2.0 * waterPlane.getZ() * waterPlane.getZ(), -2.0 * waterPlane.getZ() * waterPlane.getL(),
  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
  );
//set new camera position
camera.from = mReflection * camera.from;
camera.at = mReflection * camera.at;
camera.up = mReflection * camera.up;
```

The (projective) texture coordinates are calculated this way in the shader:

```
vec4 mvpvertex = mvp * vec4(vertex, 1.0);
vec4 tmp = vec4(1.0 / mvpvertex.w);
vec4 projCoord = mvpvertex * tmp;
projCoord += vec4(1.0);
projCoord *= vec4(0.5);
projCoord = clamp(projCoord, 0.0, 1.0);
//without this line, my reflection would be mirrored along the middle of the screen
projCoord.x = 1.0 - projCoord.x;
vec2 texCoord = projCoord.xy;
```

With this code I can rotate my plane with the help of the model matrix and everything works fine. But if I want to translate the plane along the z-Axis, so my plane looks maybe like `z = 1`, the reflection doesn't look right anymore.
The new camera position is calculated right (tested it with a debugger) but I think this line makes problems: `projCoord.x = 1.0 - projCoord.x;`

I added it because otherwise my reflection was mirrored along the y-Axis in the middle of the screen. But I don't know how I could do it in another way.
So anyone has an idea how I can fix my problem?